# Ejabberd Issue - Anonymous user can send presence stanza to roster member

Tags: anonymous, ejabberd, user-presence

I was under the assumption that an anonymous user cannot send a presence stanza to a registered user without a subscription. But using Ejabberd 2.1.2 this is happening.

How can i stop anonymous users from sending presence stanzas to registered users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use mod_filter. See

http://www.ejabberd.im/node/3956#comment-55515

and

http://www.ejabberd.im/mod_filter

Example #4 specifically shows how to prevent anon users from sending presence to regular members.